# Running post-synthesis in Xilinx ISE

Tags: vhdl, simulation, xilinx-ise

How can I run a post-synthesis simulation in Xilinx ISE? I have searched a lot and seen 1 solution on the xilinx website, but wasn't successful in applying it:
https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/45668.html

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Here we can help you with coding questions. This is not such a question. The answer to your question is simply "yes". See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I will abide by the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your software. There is no such piece of software called "Xilinx". Xilinx is a company that makes multiple different things.

Some reference documents from Xilinx:

1. [Vivado Design Suite User Guide: Logic Simulation](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_1/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation.pdf)
2. [Vivado Design Suite Tutorial: Logic Simulation](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_1/ug937-vivado-design-suite-simulation-tutorial.pdf)
3. [ISE Synthesis and Simulation Design Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/sim.pdf)
4. [ISE Simulator (ISim) In-depth Tutorial](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/ug682.pdf)

Comment: Oh, I meant Xilinx ISE. I have generated a post-synthesis file but I don't know how to run the post-synthesis. I did as the link above said, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is defined here https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/45668?language=en_US.

In short, select Simulation View and in the drop down menu select Post-Fit.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate post synthesis simulation by selection simulation radio box on upper left corner of ISE. Select the top level model of your design and click on 'Simulate Behavioural Model' from below. Adding an image for your reference:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But, to my knowledge, that is not a post-synthesis simulation. That's a behavioral simulation without considering delays.

Comment: This is not post-synthesis simulation.